# Check resource before and after the lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I've run into code that simplified looks like this

```
inline someClass* otherClass::getSomeClass()
{
    if (m_someClass)
        return m_someClass.get();

    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_lock);
    if (m_someClass)
        return m_someClass.get();

    m_someClass= std::make_unique<someClass>(this);
    return m_someClass.get();
}
```

So it seems it's a pattern to be sure thread safety of creation of someClass object. I don't have much experience in multithreading, but this code doesn't look nice to me. Is there some other way to rewrite this or it's a way it should be?

Comment: See [tag:double-checked-locking]

Comment: I think the important question here is what happens when one thread calls `getSomeClass` without getting a lock while another thread is in the middle of `getSomeClass` and constructing a new object with the lock held. I suspect it's UB.

Comment: Also I'm not super familiar with the Most Vexing Parse but `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_lock);` possibly has no effect at all and should be rewritten to look not like a function definition, e.g. as `auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>{m_lock};` or even `auto lock = std::unique_lock{m_lock};` if you have at least C++17 and CTAD enabled

Comment: @alterigel I think `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_lock);` is not subject to MVP, since `m_lock` cannot be confused as a typename for a function parameter. But in any case, `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock{m_lock};` would suffice, no need for `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem here is that you are violating the C++ memory model.  In the C++ memory model, a write operation and a read operation to the same data must be synchronized.

The `m_someClass` at the front is reading what is written to in the mutex.

It is possible that the `operator bool` on `m_someClass` is atomic somehow.

Also, your code doesn't handle the object ever being destroyed.

If it is atomic, then you should possibly be using atomic operations to update it and not a lock.  Such a pattern can result in "wasted" objects being created; often this is worth the cost of removing the lock.

make `m_someClass` be `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<someClass>>`.

Return `std::shared_ptr<someClass>` from `getSomeClass`.

```
auto existing = m_someClass.load();
if (existing)
  return existing;

auto created = std::make_shared<someClass>(this);
if (
  m_someClass.compare_exchange_strong(existing, created)
) {
  return created;
} else {
  return existing;
}
```

Two threads can both create a new `someClass` if they both try to get at the same time, but only one will persist, the other will be discarded, and the function will return the one that persists.